# Open sets in infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $C$ be an closed subset of the Banach space $X$. I am wondering whether the following statements are equivalent for any Banach space:

1. $O$ is an open set containing $C$.
2. For every $x\in \partial C$ and every direction $y$, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $x+\epsilon y$ is in $O$.
3. For every sequence $x_n$ converging to $x\in \partial C$, there is an $N$ such that $x_n\in O$, $n\ge N$.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I guess they are all equivalent.

Comment: Try the Banach space $\mathcal{R}$ and take $C$ to be the unit interval.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Neither 2 nor 3 implies 1.

Comment: @WilliamElliot How does 3 not imply 1?

Comment: @SaraWinslet,  See answer.

Answer (score 0):

3 does not imply 1.
Let X = R, C = {1}, O = [0,2].
O is a nhood of C could get you better results.